# How to set columns for large displays?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have `div` block that has CSS class:

```
<div class="col-md-5"></div>
```

How to set `col-md-4` for large displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this
`<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5"></div>`

Comment: I need to use `class="col-md-5"` for middle displayes and class="col-md-4" for large

Comment: so you use ```<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4"></div> ```

Comment: @OPV, for middle display you can use `col-md-5` and large display you can use `col-lg-4`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use col-md for large displays; use col-lg-n